# Getting MulterError: Unexpected field in React Native multiple images upload

Tags: node.js, react-native, file-upload, multer

I am currently working on a React Native App that allows the user to edit their posts and upload multiple images and save them in a NodeJS server.

I am using axios to send the data to the server.

My client side looks like:

```
const data = new FormData()
const images = [
    'path/to/file1',
    'path/to/file2',
    '...'
]
images.forEach(img => {
    data.append('images', {
        uri: img,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpeg'
    })
})

axios.put('http://localhost:5000/images', data)
```

My server side looks like:

```
Router.route('/images')
    .put(upload.array('images', 20), (req, res) => {
        //do some stuff here
    })
```

The variable upload is the configuration of multer where I specify the destination path and the image name.

I made some researches to find out the problem but nothing worked...

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

**EDIT**

I am still getting the error event if I don't provide any image and send an empty data object.

Here is what I get when I console.log the FormData:

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "images",
      Object {
        "name": "image.jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B84E8479-475C-4727-A4A4-B77AA9980897&ext=JPG",
      },
    ],
    Array [
      "images",
      Object {
        "name": "image.jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473&ext=JPG",
      },
    ],
    Array [
      "images",
      Object {
        "name": "image.jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you verify if it works when you perform the request e.g. through postman?

Comment: I just tried it on postman and it worked as expected. I used the form-data in the body with a key value pair (images, file)

Comment: make sure that the request is not being sent as an array; the keys should all be `images` and not `images[0], images[1]` and so on

Comment: I just added the response I get when I console.log() the FormData. Is that correct?